# Solving Modulus Inequalities: When to use and not use distributive property

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I'm going to use examples to explain what I mean.

> Solve $|d| + 6 \leq 10$.

\begin{align}
|d| + 6 \leq 10
\implies d + 6 \leq 10
\implies d \leq 4
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
-d-6 \leq 10 \implies
-d \leq 16
\end{align}
So, $d \leq 4$ or $d \leq -16$

is incorrect. Why? It seems to make sense to me. The only difference I can see between this and other questions I got correct is that I distributed the negative sign first (or, earlier compared to the rest.)

Comment: your example layout is confused and hard to follow. Within that, if d<0 then $|d|+6$ is $-d + 6$, not $-d - 6$. Also, if $-d\le 16$ then $d\ge -16$

Comment: Your equation is unclear.  If you mean to say $|d|+6 \leq 10$ then $|d| \leq 4 \rightarrow d = \pm 4$.  If it's a longer equation, that should be specified as such.

Comment: @Paul Thanks, now I worked out what I've done wrong in this question :) Maybe this question should be closed, I don't think it will be helpful to anyone else.